# MySQL query date ranges

Tags: mysql, date, select, range

I have googled but did not find anything related. I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| roomID |    date    | price |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  1     | 2012-10-10 |   10  |
|  1     | 2012-10-11 |   10  |
|  1     | 2012-10-12 |   10  |
|  1     | 2012-10-13 |   12  |
|  2     | 2012-10-10 |   15  |
|  2     | 2012-10-11 |   15  |
|  2     | 2012-10-12 |   15  |
|  2     | 2012-10-13 |   16  |
|  2     | 2012-10-14 |   16  |
|  2     | 2012-10-15 |   16  |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I need to get periods based on price and roomID:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| roomID |    from    |    till    | price |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|    1   | 2012-10-10 | 2012-10-12 |   10  |
|    1   | 2012-10-13 | 2012-10-13 |   12  |
|    2   | 2012-10-10 | 2012-10-12 |   15  |
|    2   | 2012-10-13 | 2012-10-15 |   16  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select roomid,
       min(date) as from,
       max(date) as till,
       price
from periods
group by price
order by price
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT roomid, MIN(date) AS `from`, MAX(date) AS `till`, price
FROM tableName
GROUP BY price
ORDER BY price
```

Comment: +1 for using backticks ( ` ) over key words as column/expression names.